# How to extend a line segment in Python?

Tags: algorithm

I have a line segment defined as its starting and ending points.

```
L = [(x1, y1), (x2, y2)]
```

So

```
               (x1, y1)                       (x2, y2)
L:                A-------------------------------B
```

I now wish to **extend the line** by pulling apart these two points like so

```
              a                                         a
L:      A'--------A-------------------------------B-----------B'
```

So I need to update the coordinates of point `A` and `B`.

Suppose `A'A = B'B = a`

How to do it in Python?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19310735/extending-a-line-segment-in-matplotlib) may be quite related, but mine mainly focuses on the algorithm that does the task, instead of visualizing it in the figure.

Comment: You do it in python just like in any other language - by computing the translation and adding to the coordinates, this is not even close to the programming issue

Comment: I think this is a math problem rather than a python problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using vector math:

```
B = A + v
where
   v = B - A = (x2-x1, y2-y1)
   ||v|| = sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2)

The normalized vector v^ with ||v^|| = 1 is: v^ = v / ||v||

To get the values of A' and B' you can now use the direction
of v^ and the length of a:
   B' = B + a * v^
   A' = A - a * v^
```