# Plotting a reference line over facet plots

Tags: python, seaborn, facet, facet-grid

I need to scatter plot data with its own line by type with a comparison to a reference line for each facet. I am wrestling with getting the line equation y=8x+10 to plot on each facet plot.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import seaborn as sns

    sns.lmplot(x="18O‰ VSMOW", y="D‰ VSMOW", hue="Type",
        col="Type", col_wrap=2, data=df)
```

My goal is to enable easy comparison of each Type to a known general relationship. Below, I drew in what I would like on the top two plots:

[image: Current Plot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- As of matplotlib 3.3, [use `axline()` to easily plot reference lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71094879/13138364).
- Figure-level functions like `lmplot` return a FacetGrid, so store the grid to access the facets.

Either use [`FacetGrid.map_dataframe()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.map_dataframe.html) to apply `axline` to each facet:

```
# store underlying facet grid
g = sns.lmplot(x='total_bill', y='tip', col='day', hue='day', col_wrap=2, data=df)

# apply axline to each facet (y = 0.18*x - 0.3)
g.map_dataframe(lambda data, **kws: plt.axline((0, -0.3), slope=0.18))
```

Or iterate the facets manually via `g.axes.flat`:

```py
for ax in g.axes.flat:
    ax.axline((0, -0.3), slope=0.18) # y = 0.18*x - 0.3
```

[image]